# Visual Studio Linker not loading library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I have just installed the MySQL Connector/C++ by downloading it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=480177) and moving the contents of `include` in `/usr/include` and the contents of `lib64` in `/usr/lib`. I also added the linker option `-lmysqlcppconn8` in the command line linker options of Visual Studio.

**Code:**

```
/* Other includes... */
#include<mysqlx/xdevapi.h>

int main(const int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    mysqlx::Session sess("localhost", 33060, "root", "MY_PW");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I now include `mysqlx/xdevapi.h` in my project and initialize a *Session* as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/database-connection-example.html) I get these errors:

```
1>Validating architecture
1>Starting remote build
1>Compiling sources:
1>Linking objects
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `mysqlx::common::Value::Value(std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&)':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/common/value.h(119): error : undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::common::Value'
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/common/value.h(119): error : undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::common::Value'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `mysqlx::common::Value::Value(unsigned long)':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/common/value.h(129): error : undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::common::Value'
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/common/value.h(129): error : undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::common::Value'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `mysqlx::common::Value::~Value()':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/common/value.h(56): error : undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::common::Value'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : /usr/include/mysqlx/common/value.h:56: more undefined references to `vtable for mysqlx::common::Value' follow
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `mysqlx::string::string(char const*)':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/devapi/common.h(100): error : undefined reference to `mysqlx::string::Impl::from_utf8(mysqlx::string&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `mysqlx::string::string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/devapi/common.h(105): error : undefined reference to `mysqlx::string::Impl::from_utf8(mysqlx::string&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `mysqlx::string::operator std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >[abi:cxx11]() const':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/devapi/common.h(115): error : undefined reference to `mysqlx::string::Impl::to_utf8[abi:cxx11](mysqlx::string const&)'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `mysqlx::DbDoc::DbDoc()':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/devapi/document.h(153): error : undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::DbDoc'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `mysqlx::DbDoc::~DbDoc()':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/devapi/document.h(127): error : undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::DbDoc'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `mysqlx::Value::print(std::ostream&) const':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/devapi/document.h(507): error : undefined reference to `mysqlx::common::Value::print(std::ostream&) const'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `mysqlx::common::Value::Value(mysqlx::common::Value&&)':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/common/value.h(56): error : undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::common::Value'
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/common/value.h(56): error : undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::common::Value'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `mysqlx::common::Value::Value(mysqlx::common::Value const&)':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/common/value.h(56): error : undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::common::Value'
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/common/value.h(56): error : undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::common::Value'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::~Session_detail()':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/devapi/detail/session.h(369): error : undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::close()'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `mysqlx::Session::Session(mysqlx::SessionSettings)':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/xdevapi.h(1101): error : undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::Session_detail(mysqlx::common::Settings_impl&)'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `void mysqlx::internal::Settings_detail<mysqlx::internal::Settings_traits>::set<true, mysqlx::SessionOption, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, mysqlx::SessionOption, unsigned int&, mysqlx::SessionOption, mysqlx::string const&>(mysqlx::SessionOption, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, mysqlx::SessionOption&&, unsigned int&, mysqlx::SessionOption&&, mysqlx::string const&)':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/devapi/detail/settings.h(67): error : undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Settings_detail<mysqlx::internal::Settings_traits>::do_set(std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<int, mysqlx::common::Value>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, mysqlx::common::Value> > >&&)'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `void mysqlx::internal::Settings_detail<mysqlx::internal::Settings_traits>::set<true, mysqlx::SessionOption, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(mysqlx::SessionOption, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&)':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/devapi/detail/settings.h(67): error : undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Settings_detail<mysqlx::internal::Settings_traits>::do_set(std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<int, mysqlx::common::Value>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, mysqlx::common::Value> > >&&)'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : In function `void mysqlx::internal::Settings_detail<mysqlx::internal::Settings_traits>::set<true, mysqlx::SessionOption, mysqlx::string const&>(mysqlx::SessionOption, mysqlx::string const&)':
1>/usr/include/mysqlx/devapi/detail/settings.h(67): error : undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Settings_detail<mysqlx::internal::Settings_traits>::do_set(std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<int, mysqlx::common::Value>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, mysqlx::common::Value> > >&&)'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : (.rodata._ZTCN6mysqlx5ValueE0_NS_6common5ValueE[_ZTVN6mysqlx5ValueE]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for mysqlx::common::Value'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : (.rodata._ZTCN6mysqlx5ValueE0_NS_6common5ValueE[_ZTVN6mysqlx5ValueE]+0x20): undefined reference to `mysqlx::common::Value::print(std::ostream&) const'
1>C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\obj\x64\Debug\Main.o : error : (.rodata._ZTIN6mysqlx5ValueE[_ZTIN6mysqlx5ValueE]+0x28): undefined reference to `typeinfo for mysqlx::common::Value'
1>collect2 : error : ld returned 1 exit status
1>Done building project "LSTGA.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Additional information:**

- Remote OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64
- MySQL Server: 8.0.13 (XPlugin enabled)
- gcc / g++: 5.4.0 (same as in BUILDINFO.txt of MySQL Connector)

Thanks in advance. -*Minding*

Comment: Is there any option to show the linker command Visual Studio is trying to run?

Comment: @Hitobat I can't find one, it only says `-o"C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\LSTGA\LSTGA\bin\x64\Debug\LSTGA.out" "3600000" -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--no-undefined "g++" -Wl,-z,now` under Linker -> Command Line but `-lmysqlcppconn8` is added later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work now, by putting `mysqlcppconn8` in `Library Dependencies` instead of putting `-lmysqlcppconn8` in *Additional Options* (both under **Project > Properties > Linker**). Visual studio generates `-l"mysqlcppconn8"` and it works perfectly.

I dont know exactly why the previous didn't work but maybe it is because of the *number* in the library name requiring *quotation marks*. And either way using the `Library Dependencies` option is a much cleaner solution.

Hope this helps. *-Minding*